# Remote call from another phone

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, cellular-data, wifi-calling

I am in US now and I need to call Ukraine, it would be way too expensive as I need to make a lot of calls (business related).

I have a friend in Ukraine so I though if there was a way to connect my phone from US to his phone in Ukraine and make calls from his phone so it’s cheap.

The requirements are:

- an app that could transmit the call audio, from my phone to his phone to the final destination phone, back and forth.
- less expensive than cellular service between US and Ukraine (but willing to pay in setup time, service or for an app if it will work)

Is there some way to do that with both of us using iOS and iPhones?

Comment: Looks off-topic here, (unless it’s about Apple hardware or software). Consider asking on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @NimeshNeema we explicitly allow software recommendation questions here if you’re using apple hardware so iPhone makes this on topic here. Now this question needs an edit to clarify what the requirements are to separate it from a shopping question, so it might need to be placed on hold for other reasons.

Comment: I’ve edited this to be less about shopping but indicate that a free / cost saving solution is a factor in the solution fitting your needs.

Comment: Doesn't Skype with a local callout (which AFAIK it does by default) help here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a voice relay. Suggest you consider an Android phone. Apple would never approve such an app.

Comment: Why wouldn’t a voip solution work here?